# spacy GPU process not working while installed prerequisites

Tags: python, spacy

I have installed `spacy 2.3.0` from source and then according to [this post](https://mc.ai/spacy-training-using-gpu/) installed `thinc_gpu_ops-0.0.4` and `cupy[101]-7.6.0`.
But this code returns `False`:

```
thinc_gpu_ops.AVAILABLE
```

My `Cuda` version is 10.1 and I'm working in `Linux 20`.

*P.S: I don't know if it helps but `tensorflow` lib detects 2 GPUs correctly using the code below:*

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

Answer (score 0):

`thinc-gpu-ops` is no longer used as of spaCy v2.2.2. If you have CUDA 10.1, install `cupy-cuda101` or `spacy[cuda101]`.

You can check with `spacy.require_gpu()` to see whether the GPU is detected correctly. If it isn't, it raises an error.

Comment: I can't install `spacy[cuda101]` because I want to change the source.However, I did uninstall `cupy-cuda100` and installed `cupy-cuda101` but it didn't work

Comment: All you should need is to have `cupy-cuda101` (or whichever is the correct version) installed and working and then spacy should detect it correctly. Check that `cupy` is working as intended and maybe also that you don't have the package `cupy` installed, too, which would cause conflicts.

Comment: Don't you have any idea yet?